# Phone gap - meta tags to hide the address bar?

Tags: browser, cordova

I have seen so many questions on hiding the address bar.  I am developing a native phone gap application.  In other words, a set of html pages with javascript files hosted on a server targeted for mobile users  (Not inside iPhone/android apps).  In such a case, is there a way to hide the address bar after the first loading of the page?

Thank you for your help

Comment: so it will be a phonegap application but the html files will be displayed from server, right??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334434/how-to-hide-address-bar-in-android-phonegap-without-using-the-domain-whitelist

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible with this little Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// When ready...
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
   // Set a timeout...
   setTimeout(function(){
      // Hide the address bar!
      window.scrollTo(0, 1);
   }, 0);
});
</script>
```

You should add it somewhere in the `<head>` of your HTML code.

The `window.scrollTo` method is the key to hiding the address bar. The wrapping `setTimeout` function is required by the iPhone to properly hide the address bar – not using setTimeout will cause problems.

---

When you want to support adding webpages to the homescreen on the iPhone as well, you'll need to add the following `<meta>`-tag too.

```
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

This will also hide the toolbar at the bottom of the screen on the iPhone (only when added to homescreen by user).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334434/how-to-hide-address-bar-in-android-phonegap-without-using-the-domain-whitelist