# How to hide address bar in android phonegap without using the domain whitelist?

Tags: android, cordova

Can anyone tell me how to hide the address bar in the android phonegap.I am trying to capture image but the image functionality is not working in the phonegap.where as the same is working in the browser.So,I want to hide the address bar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible with this little Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// When ready...
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
// Set a timeout...
setTimeout(function(){
  // Hide the address bar!
  window.scrollTo(0, 1);
}, 0);
});
```

You should add it somewhere in the `<head>` of your HTML code.

The `window.scrollTo` method is the key to hiding the address bar. The wrapping `setTimeout` function is required by the Phone to properly hide the address bar – not using setTimeout will cause problems.

When you want to support adding webpages to the homescreen on the iPhone as well, you'll need to add the following `<meta>`-tag too.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

This will also hide the toolbar at the bottom of the screen on the iPhone (only when added to homescreen by user).

or with using [ChildBrowser PhoneGap plugin](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser)